Outer semidirect product
Suppose we have a group $G$ and two homs $L, R: G \rightarrow G$ such that $L^2 = L$, $R^2 = R$, and $LR = RL$. The first two conditions tell us that $L$ and $R$ are retractions followed by their inclusions back into $G$. The final condition lets us do the following inner construction: define $$\newcommand{\im}[0]{\operatorname{im}}
A = \ker L \cap \im R \\
B = \ker L \cap \ker R \\
C = \im L \cap \ker R \\
D = \im L \cap \im R
$$
and note that $A, B, C, D$ are pairwise disjoint because $\ker L \cap \im L = \ker R \cap \im R = \{e\}$ by how retractions work. Further, observe that given $g \in G$, $$\newcommand{\-}[0]{^{-1}}
g = R(gL(g\-)) \cdot LR(g)R(g\-)gL(g\-) \cdot L(gR(g\-)) \cdot LR(g)
$$
which proves that every $g$ admits a factorization into $abcd$ where $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $c \in C$, $d \in D$. Further, if $abcd = a'b'c'd'$, we can apply $L$ to both sides to yield $cd = c'd'$, and thus $c'^{-1}c = d'd^{-1} = e$ by disjointness and thus $c = c', d = d'$, and we can apply a similar argument to then prove $a = a', b = b'$. This proves that this factorization is unique. Finally, we can rewrite $G$'s multiplication like so: $$\newcommand{\-}[0]{^{-1}}
(a, b, c, d) \cdot (a', b', c', d') = (ada'd\-, da'\-d\-bcda'b'd\-c\-, cdc'd\-, dd')
$$
I know this looks like a random string of letters but this is precisely what works out; you can verify this by checking that each factor is indeed in the appropriate kernel and/or image of $L$ and $R$. My question is whether there is an outer version of this construction, analogous to the typical semidirect product. In other words, I want that, given $A, B, C, D$ and some other data, we can always recover $G, L, R$, and that every possible $G, L, R$ can be constructed this way.

I haven’t managed to parse your question, but I am puzzled that it looks symmetrical in $L$ and $R$. If a group can be decomposed as a semidirect product “both ways round” then it’s a direct product.

To see this, you need to prove the lemma that normal subgroups with trivial intersection have to commute.

@HJRW $L$ and $R$ are independent idempotent endomorphisms that happen to commute. Each one expresses $G$ as a semidirect product, but not with the same factors. It's really not "both ways round". In other words, $G$ has a three term normal filtration with $B$ at the bottom, then $A\times C$ in the middle, and then $D$ at the top. The commutator of $A$ and $C$ is in $B$.

@HJRW is there anything I can do to make it clearer? I'm not very good at writing things in an understandable way the first time around, but I tried my best here.

@Keith My guess is that the confusion was caused by your usage of semidirect product in the title.

@verret good point— I wanted to call it a "double" semidirect product, but it seems this generally used for when we take a semidirect of a semidirect, which has 3 components, not 4. Then I wanted to call it "orthogonal" because in my head, it's like the retractions are perpendicular to each other, but apparently "orthogonal projection" already has an unrelated meaning as well. So I just left the title vague. Feel free to edit it to be clearer— I'm still not sure what to title this question.

@DaveBenson: unless I misunderstood, your comment seems to answer the question: $G=B\rtimes (A\times C)\rtimes D$ is surely the “outer” construction asked for, with $L$ and $R$ the natural retractions onto $A\rtimes D$ and $C\rtimes D$. (Added: Oh, I think this is exactly what Tom Goodwillie just wrote in the posted answer.)

Actually, no, I don't think there's necessarily a complementary copy of $A\times C$ in the kernel of $G \to D$.

Here's an example. Let $G=\langle s,t\mid s^2,t^2,(st)^4\rangle$, a dihedral group of order eight, $L\colon s\mapsto s$, $t\mapsto 1$, $R\colon s\mapsto 1$, $t\mapsto t$. Then $A={1,t}$, $B={1,stst}$, $C={1,s}$, $D={1}$, and $[A,C]=B$.

I've deleted my wrong-guess answer.

$\newcommand\im{\operatorname{im}}\newcommand\1{^{-1}}$ Since $B$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, conjugation defines actions of $A$, $C$ and $D$ on $B$. Moreover $D$ normalizes both $A$ and $C$, so there are actions of $D$ on $A$ and $C$. For better readability, let us use both left and right actions, they are interdefinable through $x^y={^{y\1}x}$. These actions satisfy the identities
$$
{^d}(b^a)=(^db)^{^da},\ (^cb)^d={^{c^d}}(b^d).
$$
Since $a\1cac\1\in B$ for any $a\in A$, $c\in C$, we also have a map $-\otimes-:A\times C\to B$ satisfying
$$
(a_1a_2)\otimes c=(a_1\otimes c)^{a_2}\cdot(a_2\otimes c),\quad 
a\otimes(c_1c_2)=(a\otimes c_1)\cdot{^{c_1}(a\otimes c_2)},
$$
$$
{}^d(a\otimes c)=(^da)\otimes(^dc),
$$
and
$$
(^cb)^a\cdot(a\otimes c)=(a\otimes c)\cdot{^c(b^a)}.
$$
Given the above data, $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient of the free product $A*B*C*D$ by the relations $a\1ba\sim b^a$, $cbc\1\sim{^cb}$, $dad\1\sim{^da}$, $dcd\1\sim{^dc}$, $dbd\1\sim{^db}$ and $a\1cac\1\sim a\otimes c$.
For the proof, note that under these relations, any element of the free product is equivalent to a product of the form $abcd$, hence the obvious homomorphism $A*B*C*D\to G$ induces an isomorphism from the quotient to $G$.
Explicitly, the resulting product on $A\times B\times C\times D$ is given by
$$
(a,b,c,d)(a',b',c',d')=(a\,{^d\!a'},b^{^da'}\!\!\cdot(^d\!a'\otimes c)\cdot^c\!\!(^db'),c\,^d\!c',dd').
$$
It requires some effort, but one can check that this product is associative iff the above identities hold. Moreover for all $a,b,c,d$ there exist unique $a',b',c',d'$ with $(a,b,c,d)(a',b',c',d')=(1,1,1,1)$.
See comments for another derivation by LSpice. Still another way to check it: using the above relations, in the quotient of the free product by them we can replace $ba\mapsto a\,b^a$, $cb\mapsto{^cb}\,c$, $da\mapsto{^da}\,d$, $dc\mapsto{^dc}\,d$, $db\mapsto{^db}\,d$, and $ca\mapsto a(a\otimes c)c$. Hence in this quotient we can transform $abcda'b'c'd'$ as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{lccccccccc}
 &a&b&c&&d&a'&b'&c'&d'\\
&&&&&\searrow&\swarrow\\
\sim&a&b&c&&^d\!a'&d&b'&c'&d'\\
&&&&\searrow\!\!\!\!\!\!\swarrow\\
\sim&a&b&^d\!a'&^d\!a'\otimes c&c&d&b'&c'&d'\\
&&\searrow&\swarrow\\
\sim&a&^d\!a'&b^{^da'}&^d\!a'\otimes c&c&d&b'&c'&d'\\
&&&&&&\searrow&\swarrow\\
\sim&a&^d\!a'&b^{^da'}&^d\!a'\otimes c&c&^db'&d&c'&d'\\
&&&&&\searrow&\swarrow\\
\sim&a&^d\!a'&b^{^da'}&^d\!a'\otimes c&^c\!(^db')&c&d&c'&d'\\
&&&&&&&\searrow&\swarrow\\
\sim&a&^d\!a'&b^{^da'}&^d\!a'\otimes c&^c\!(^db')&c&^d\!c'&d&d'
\end{array}
$$

You also need to prove that given these data, there's no further collapse. That's the point of the properties of $\otimes$.

@DaveBenson does not this follow from the fact that all relations do hold in $G$?

$G$ doesn't a priori exist, for such an "outer" definition.

Let me think about it. In the meanwhile, do you agree that given $G$ as in OP what I wrote is true?

The only thing unclear to me is that the properties of $\otimes$ you give are enough to prevent further collapse. If you like, this amounts to verifying the associative law for the product defined by your data on 4-tuples. This exactly parallels the situation for semidirect products.

Sorry I don't understand. Let us expand this. Which of the following is doubtful? (1) I unambiguously define a group by generators and relations. (2) Every element of this group is isomorphic to an element of the form $abcd$. (3) I get a homomorphism from this group to $G$ as in OP. (4) This homomorphism is surjective since $G$ is generated by $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. (5) This homomorphism is injective since the relations by which I quotient all hold in $G$.

None of the above. As I said, it's a question of providing an external construction of a group.

I agree that giving an explicit group structure on $A\times B\times C\times D$ is more explicit than giving by generators and relations a group with a bijection to $A\times B\times C\times D$. I will try to do it. Actually I now realize that I need some more relations to move $a\otimes c$ past $A$ or $C$...

What does "isomorphic" mean of an element of a group in (2)? Is it just "equal"? If so, then I think that the question in (2) becomes not just whether every element of your new group is equal to such a product—which now also is in doubt?—but then whether it is equal to a unique such product, i.e., whether there is further collapse, as @DaveBenson says.

@LSpice Sorry, yes, by "isomorphic" I actually meant "equal". As for your further question: we have a homomorphism to $G$ sending $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ to themselves, and by OP in $G$ every element is equal to a unique product of the form $abcd$.

Re, but I thought that the whole point is that we don't have such a homomorphism, because, as @DaveBenson says, we don't have $G$—since we're trying to come up with a way to construct a group on the basis of "$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and some other data", presumably not including $G$ itself.  (Or, to say it differently, we want to know how to recognise valid "other data" without already knowing the existence of $G$; so the question seems to be whether the data you've given guarantee $G$ exists.)

I think that the multiplication map is $$(a_1, b_1, c_1, d_1)(a_2, b_2, c_2, d_2) = \bigl(a_1\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2), \varphi_{A, B}\bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2^{-1}), b_1\cdot(c_1^{-1} \otimes \varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2))\bigr)\varphi_{C, B}(c_1, \varphi_{D, B}(d_1, b_2)), c_1\varphi_{D, C}(d_1, c_2), d_1 d_2\bigr),$$ where $\varphi_{G, H}$ is the given action of $G$ on $H$.

Sorry, I switched the order of the arguments to $\otimes$. Identity obviously $(1_A, 1_B, 1_C, 1_D)$, inverse $(a, b, c, d)^{-1} = \bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d^{-1}, a^{-1}), \varphi_{D, B}\bigl(d^{-1}, \varphi_{C, B}(c^{-1}, (a \otimes c^{-1})\cdot\varphi_{A, B}(a, b^{-1}))\bigr), \varphi_{D, C}(d^{-1}, c^{-1}), d^{-1})$.

Since projections from $A \times B \times C \times D$ to $A \rtimes D$ and $C \rtimes D$ are hom.s, to show assoc., suffices to show it in $B$ component: need to show $$\varphi_{A, B}\bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1 d_2, a_3^{-1}), \varphi_{A, B}\bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2^{-1}), b_1\cdot(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2) \otimes c_1^{-1})\bigr)\varphi_{C, B}(c_1, \varphi_{D, B}(d_1, b_2))\cdot(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1 d_2, a_3) \otimes \varphi_{D, C}(d_1, c_2^{-1})c_1^{-1})\bigr)\varphi_{C, B}(c_1\varphi_{D, C}(d_1, c_2), \varphi_{D, B}(d_1 d_2, b_3))$$ …

… (the $B$-component of $(g_1 g_2)g_3)$ equals $$\varphi_{A, B}\bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, \varphi_{D, A}(d_2, a_3^{-1})a_2^{-1}), b_1\cdot(\varphi_{D, A}(d_1, a_2\varphi_{D, A}(d_2, a_3)) \otimes c_1^{-1})\bigr)\varphi_{C, B}\bigl(c_1, \varphi_{D, B}(d_1, \varphi_{A, B}\bigl(\varphi_{D, A}(d_2, a_3^{-1}), b_2\cdot(\varphi_{D, A}(d_2, a_3) \otimes c_2^{-1})\bigr)\varphi_{C, B}(c_2, \varphi_{D, B}(d_2, b_3)))\bigr)$$ (the $B$-component of $g_1(g_2 g_3)$), on the (obviously implausible!) assumption that I haven't made a mistake somewhere.

@LSpice Many thanks for your work! I also checked it in Mathematica.

In case anyone checks, my comments were made when the definition of $\otimes$ seemed to be $a \otimes c = c^{-1}ac a^{-1}$, so my $a \otimes c$ is $(a^{-1} \otimes c)^c$ with the new definition $a \otimes c = a^{-1}c a c^{-1}$. Anyway, the hard part was of course მამუკაჯიბლაძე's identification of that commutator map as the important additional structure.

@DaveBenson Could you have a look at the new version?

I find it interesting that your multiplication with the new definition of $\otimes$ is entirely ‘positive’, i.e., we never explicitly use inverses, so could (I think) do all this just as well in a semigroup, at the expense of left and right actions no longer being interconvertible.

@LSpice Semidirect products certainly exist for monoids, in fact more generally for functors from small categories to small categories, they are given by the Grothendieck construction. It might be that what you say can be realized as similar construction for double categories in place of categories...

@LSpice do you think you could organize your response into an answer? It is a bit all over the place being scattered across many comments, but I'm interested in understanding it better.

@Keith, re, I can if you really want, but the only significance of these comments was before the explicit multiplication formula on $A \times B \times C \times D$ was part of the answer on which we're commenting.  Since the essential idea (the commutator $A \times C \to B$) came from this answer, and since this answer now contains everything I wrote except the formula for $g^{-1}$ and the expansion of $(g_1 g_2)g_3$ vs. $g_1(g_2 g_3)$, both of which are purely mechanical, I don't think that there's much to be gained.

@LSpice ah, fair enough. This answer mentions your derivation as an alternative, that's why I asked. No need if it would be redundant.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე This is very impressive! I think the main omission I noticed is verifying that we can define $L$ and $R$ as retractions, but this comes down to proving $e \otimes c = a \otimes e = e$ for all $a, c$. This observation does suggest why you chose $\otimes$ as a symbol, as this behavior is reminiscent of a tensor product. I should probably check if there's a simplification in the language of tensor products of groups... todo for myself for later. Either way, I better award this bounty now that I'm confident this is correct.

Thank you! Indeed that $L(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,c,d)$ and $R(a,b,c,d)=(a,1,1,d)$ are homomorphisms follows from what you write, and the latter follow from $a\otimes c=(ae)\otimes c=(a\otimes c)\cdot(e\otimes c)$ and from $a\otimes c=a\otimes(ec)=(a\otimes e)\cdot(a\otimes c)$
